# Best way to update Kubernetes secret from command line

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The kubernetes dashboard allows one to see secrets in plain text (*not* base64 encoded) and make an easy change to any key-value pair within a Secret. I cannot find a way to easily make a similar change on the command line.

My best attempt has been to write a script which uses `kubectl get secret` to pull all of the data in Json format, grab each key-value pair, base64 decode the values, update the one I actually want, then feed them all back in to `kubectl apply`. After running into multiple issues I figured there is probably a `kubectl` option that I'm overlooking which will allow me to update just one key-value pair in a given Secret.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have your secrets manifest stashed somewhere where it is secure.

I dont usually change the secrets using the dashboard, but instead do a kubectl apply -f mysecret.yaml.  the mysecret.yaml file keeps the latest and greatest values.  No in-place editing.  This way you get consistency across deployments.

Comment: Yes, my guess is this is a commonly accepted practice but - as I've run into recently - problems arise when that manifest that everyone hangs on to (because naturally they keep handy copies instead of always reaching into to some central source of truth) isn't always consistent